# Log4j.Debug=true not priniting anything on weblogic

Tags: log4j, weblogic-10.x, java-6

I am using weblogic 10.3.6 and Iam trying to use log4j1.2 for logging purposes. 
I have created log4j.xml in src/main/resources. 
But log4j is not creating any file or nor even logging on console.

I tried giving jvm property **-Dlog4j.debug=true** but even that is not printing anything on console.

Any pointers?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/" debug="true">
    <!-- Console Appender -->
    <appender name="console" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
        <param name="Target" value="System.out" />
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%-5p | %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} | [%t] %C{2} (%F:%L) - %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>
    <!-- Info Log File Appender -->
    <appender name="info-log" class="org.apache.log4j.FileAppender">
        <param name="File" value="C:\\Users\\rajan.d.panchal\\Desktop\\newlog\\info.log" />
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%-5p | %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} | [%t] %C{2} (%F:%L) - %m%n" />
        </layout>
        <filter class="org.apache.log4j.varia.LevelRangeFilter">
            <param name="LevelMin" value="debug" />
            <param name="LevelMax" value="info" />
            <param name="AcceptOnMatch" value="true" />
        </filter>
    </appender>
    <!-- Error Log File Appender -->
    <appender name="error-log" class="org.apache.log4j.FileAppender">
        <param name="Append" value="false" />
        <param name="File" value="C:\\Users\\abc\\Desktop\\newlog\\error.log" />
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%-5p | %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} | [%t] %C{2} (%F:%L) - %m%n" />
        </layout>
        <filter class="org.apache.log4j.varia.LevelRangeFilter">
            <param name="LevelMin" value="warn" />
            <param name="LevelMax" value="fatal" />
            <param name="AcceptOnMatch" value="true" />
        </filter>
    </appender>
    <logger name="com.jcg.log4j.example" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="info-log" />
        <appender-ref ref="error-log" />
    </logger>
    <root>
        <level value="debug" />
        <appender-ref ref="console" />
    </root>
</log4j:configuration>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. So I was using JRebel and It was not creating any logs. After disabling JRebel it worked.